# Fabric.js - objects not updating cached position?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

That's a hard title to write as I'm not entirely sure what the issue is here, but I assume it's to do with how Fabric.js caches object properties.

Say I create a rectangle:

```
let foo = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    fill: 'green'
});
canvas.add(foo);
canvas.renderAll();
```

And I want to change its fill on hover:

```
canvas.on('mouse:hover', evt => {
    if (!evt.target) return;
    evt.target.set('fill', 'green');
});
```

All works great.

However, if I programmatically change the object's position or size:

```
foo.set({left: 500});
canvas.renderAll();
```

...the event fires only if I hover over its **OLD** position, i.e. the space between tl=10,10 / tr=60,10 / br = 60,60 / bl = 10,60, not if I hover its new position at tl=500,10 / tr = 560,10 / br = 560,60 / bl = 510,60.

[image]

So it's like a cache isn't getting updated. This happens despite calling `.renderAll()` after every such change.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the document I found [here](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html) it looks like `set` just moves the image of it.

If you wish to update the event triggering zone, you need to call `setCoords` as well.

This seems to work fine:

```
foo.set({left: 500});
foo.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: Thanks. Wow, don't recall seeing that in the tutorials. Having a big issue with the impenetrability of the Fabric docs so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.